# TypeError: Cannot parse argument of type None

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating an E-Commerce with python3 and django, but I'm having a type error (TypeError: Cannot parse argument of type None.) with the pagseguro integration, and I'm not able to solve it. I am still in the process of learning and would like the help of someone with more knowledge to help me remedy this error.
Below is my code, I believe it is something related to my Class PagseguroView().

Segue meu codigo

```
class PagSeguroView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        order = get_object_or_404(
            Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user), pk=order_pk
        )
        pg = order.pagseguro()
        pg.redirect_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri(
            reverse('checkout:order_detail', args=[order.pk])
        )
        pg.notification_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri(
            reverse('checkout:pagseguro_notification')
        )
        response = pg.checkout()
        return response.payment_url
```

it might be something related to *args and **kwargs

when I inspect these two elements it returns the following:

"args" is not accessedPylance
(parameter) args: tuple[Any, ...]

Comment: You should not be using `self.kwargs` as that is at the class scope
instead just use `kwargs.get('pk')` it it should be fixed

Comment: I made the change, leaving only kwargs.get(pk), but unfortunately the error persists